# PHP: How to get proper output into file after merging every line from three or more files?

Tags: php, merge, output

I'm trying to merge all the lines from three or more files. Each line must be merged with every single line from these files. Each file could have any amount of lines.

Content of files is like this:

```
file1.txt:
    file1 line1
    file1 line2
file2.txt:
    file2 line1
    file2 line2
file3.txt:
    file3 line1
    file3 line2
```

As a PHP newbie I've wrote such a code:

```
<?php
$file1 = file("file1.txt");
$file2 = file("file2.txt");
$file3 = file("file3.txt");
$file777 = fopen("file777.txt", "w");
for($f1=0;$f1<count($file1);$f1++)
    for($f2=0;$f2<count($file2);$f2++)
        for($f3=0;$f3<count($file3);$f3++)
            fwrite($file777, "$file1[$f1] $file2[$f2] $file3[$f3]");
fclose($file777);
?>
```

But in the result file I'm getting a mess like this:

```
file1 line1
 file2 line1
 file3 line1
file1 line1
 file2 line1
 file3 line2file1 line1
 file2 line2 file3 line1
file1 line1
 file2 line2 file3 line2file1 line2 file2 line1
 file3 line1
file1 line2 file2 line1
 file3 line2file1 line2 file2 line2 file3 line1
file1 line2 file2 line2 file3 line2
```

Instead of a needed result like this:

```
file1 line1 file2 line1 file3 line1
file1 line1 file2 line1 file3 line2
file1 line1 file2 line2 file3 line1
file1 line1 file2 line2 file3 line2
file1 line2 file2 line1 file3 line1
file1 line2 file2 line1 file3 line2
file1 line2 file2 line2 file3 line1
file1 line2 file2 line2 file3 line2
```

Could you help me to get a proper output please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just realized that it is also possible to use **FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES** flag for **file()** functions, so the output will be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not removing the newlines at the end of each line.

From the php.net manual for file()

Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, **with the newline still attached**. Upon failure, file() returns FALSE.

Use trim to remove the newlines.

```
<?php
$file1 = file("file1.txt");
$file2 = file("file2.txt");
$file3 = file("file3.txt");
$file777 = fopen("file777.txt", "w");
for($f1=0;$f1<count($file1);$f1++)
    for($f2=0;$f2<count($file2);$f2++)
        for($f3=0;$f3<count($file3);$f3++)
            fwrite($file777, trim($file1[$f1]) ." ". trim($file2[$f2] ) ." ".  trim($file3[$f3]) .PHP_EOL );
fclose($file777);
?>
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just realized that there is also another way to fix my problem - using of the **FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES** flag for **file()** functions, so the output will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Whe  you call file() the output includes the newline character in each element of the array. So, you need to trim() each line  after writing:

```
fwrite($file777, trim($file1[$f1])." ".trim($file2[$f2])." ".($file3[$f3]) );
```

The last one was not trimmed, to keep the newline character after it.